# Número mayor que otro en un array

Tags: c

estoy haciendo un programa que me pide que ingrese 10 valores, saque el promedio, los ponga en sentido contrario y que me diga si alguno de los números que he ingresado es mayor que el promedio. Los dos primeros lo he hecho, pero con el último me paso me atasco, no sé como hacer que vaya comprobando número por número si un nº es mayor que el promedio, lo he intentado con un if, pero no me sale. ¿Alguna ayuda? Gracias!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define TAM 10

//Promedio = suma de una serie de números entre el número de números.
int main()
{
float n[TAM];
int i, h;
float suma=0, promedio=0,cont;

 for(i=0;i<TAM;i++){

    printf("Ingresa los 10 valores: ");
    scanf("%f", &n[i]);
    fflush(stdin);

    suma = suma + n[i];
    promedio = suma/TAM ; //Formula del promedio

}

if (n[i] > promedio){
    cont = 1;
}

if (cont = 1){
    printf("%f es mayor!", n[i]);
}


printf("\nEl promedio es: %.1f", promedio);

printf("\nEn orden inverso es: ");

for(i = TAM - 1;i>=0;i--){ //Sacado de los apuntes.
    printf(" %.1f ", n[i]);
}






return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

lo que necesitas es una variable temporal que lleve el valor del número mayor y adicionalmente usar un `if` en el que uses la variable temporal junto al valor del promedio, esto es, sí el valor de `n[i]` es mayor al `promedio` y a su vez `n[i]` es mayor a la variable `temp`, el valor de `n[i]` sería igual al nuevo valor de `temp`. Esto en código sería algo más o menos así:

```
float mayor(float n[TAM], float promedio)
{
    float temp = -FLT_MAX;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < TAM; i++)
    {
        if (n[i] > promedio && n[i] > temp)
        {
            temp = n[i];
        }
    }
    return temp;
}
```

He usado `-FLT_MAX` para obtener el valor de `float` más pequeño (negativo), ya que no conozco el dominio de los números con los que estás trabajando y tú arreglo puede tener números negativos, para poder usarlo debes usar el header `float.h`.

[Aquí](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cfloat/) encuentras la documentación de `float.h`.